# Software Updater is crashing on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: update-manager, crash, 22.10

I'm  using Ubuntu 22.10, and every time I launch the Software Updater it crashes.

Here is a screenshot.

[image: crash screenshot here]

Comment: What happens if you open a terminal and type: ```sudo apt-get update ```

Comment: Hit:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease        
Hit:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease        
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: What happens if you run the command `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` ?

Comment: ```Hit:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease               
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease                  
Reading package lists... Done                          
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```